# Java: Sort a list of Objects using Comparator with second word of the property

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have a list of `objects` which i want to sort on basis of `name`. I have done coding where it does get sorted on basis of `name` but i have a slight different requirement.

The names are for Example which i have currently sorted using the below code:

```
Bull AMP
Cat DEF
Dog AMP
Frog STR
Zebra DEF
```

But i want the name sorted on the basis of second word in the name. Basically the `list` should be something like this:

```
Bull AMP
Dog AMP
Cat DEF
Zebra DEF
Frog STR
```

Below is my code:

Object Class:

```
public class AnimalData implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3952396152688462601L;
    public String name;
    public long age;
    private String animal;
    private String animalParts;
    private String animalType;
}
```

Comparator Class

```
public class AnimalDataComparer implements Comparator<AnimalData> 
      {
  @Override
  public int compare(final AnimalData object1, final AnimalData object2) 
  {
          return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
  }
  }
```

Sorting using Collections

```
  private List<AnimalData> AnimalDataList;

  Collections.sort(AnimalDataList, AnimalDataComparer);
```

Comment: Your equals method also needs to represent that behavior.

Comment: what is AMP, DEF etc for a field??

Comment: or are those sufixes part of the field String name?

Comment: THey are categories..(AMP,DEF and STR)

Comment: The list of objects should be sorted based on the caegory and not by name

Comment: and you dont want to add a new field variable like ***private String category***???

Comment: Then just do `return object1.getCategory().compareTo(object2.getCategory())` in your `Comparator`.

Comment: You could use `split()` and compare the second part of the name.

Comment: @daniu : There is no category field. The category is a part of name which comes as second word.

Comment: @MuratK. since this is a `Comparator` not `Comparable`, it is *not* by any means required to comply with `equals()`.

Comment: This is really poor design. If at all possible, you should add separate fields for `name` and `category`. If you need it formatted like this, add a method like `String foo() { return name + " " + category; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8 Streams mode:

```
Comparator<? super Animal> animalComparator = (a, b) -> {
        StringTokenizer firstTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(a.getName(), " ");
        firstTokenizer.nextToken();
        StringTokenizer secondTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(b.getName(), " ");
        secondTokenizer.nextToken();
        return firstTokenizer.nextToken().compareTo(secondTokenizer.nextToken());
    };

    myList = myList.stream().sorted(animalComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That is not "full" Java 8 code - it duplicates comparator logic for both arguments.

Comment: Well, there are two different variables to be compared cause it's using StringTokenizer class

Answer (score 4):

Change your Comparator like this:

```
public class AnimalDataComparer implements Comparator<AnimalData> 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final AnimalData object1, final AnimalData object2) 
    {
      return object1.getName().split(" ")[1].compareTo(object2.getName().split(" ")[1]);
    }
}
```

or use Java's newer Comparator API:

```
Comparator<AnimalData> c = Comparator.comparing(animal -> animal.getName().split(" ")[1]);
```

Note that this is assuming that all names actually have two words. If you do not know that for sure, you need to check before accessing the split array.

Aside from all that, you might want to think about the other comments and split the name in your constructor and have two fields, `name` and `category`. Or you could write a getter for category, in which you do the splitting and validation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement this yourself, as follows, assuming that the word is part of `name`, with [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) and [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-):

```
@Override
public int compare(final AnimalData object1, final AnimalData object2) 
{
    return object1.getName().substring(
        object1.getName().indexOf(" ") 
    ).compareTo(object2.getName().substring(
        object2.getName().indexOf(" ")
    ));
}
```

If for some reason you have more than two words and the last is the one you want, then use [`lastIndexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

OUTPUT::

[AnimalData [name=Dog AMP], AnimalData [name=Cat DEF], AnimalData [name=Zebra DEF], AnimalData [name=Frog STR]]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        AnimalData data1 = new AnimalData("Cat DEF");
        AnimalData data2 = new AnimalData("Dog AMP");
        AnimalData data3 = new AnimalData("Frog STR");
        AnimalData data4 = new AnimalData("Zebra DEF");
        List<AnimalData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(data1);
        list.add(data2);
        list.add(data3);
        list.add(data4);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}

class AnimalData implements Serializable, Comparable<AnimalData> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3952396152688462601L;
    public String name;
    public long age;
    private String animal;
    private String animalParts;
    private String animalType;

    public AnimalData(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(AnimalData o) {
        String secondPartThis = this.name.split(" ")[1];
        String secondPartObject = o.name.split(" ")[1];
        return secondPartThis.compareTo(secondPartObject);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AnimalData [name=" + name + "]";
    }
```